# How to make Reaver crack WPS faster

Tags: network, packet, ubuntu, wps

I have Reaver 1.4 on Ubuntu 14.10 with a Realtek RTL8187SE B/G adapter and it takes almost 5-10 minutes to get from 0.01% to 0.02%. I always have my TX-Power at 30 when I use Reaver, the network is strong, and I run Airodump-ng with Reaver so I can see if I can still catch the network, and it always has lots of Beacons and "#Data" so it couldn't be that the network is weak. How can I fix this?

Comment: You're brute-forcing, more and faster processing power? Write your own GPU based Reaver?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @FiascoLabs, Reaver performs an *online* brute-force attack.  Adding more computing power does not help in this case.

Answer (score 2):

By default, after each failed attempt, Reaver delays the PIN attempt by 1 second. You can disable this 1 second delay by adding `-d 0` to your Reaver command. (This may not work well with all APs)

Also, you can use `--dh-small` flag to instruct Reaver to use small diffie-hellman secret numbers so that, computational load is reduced on the target AP.

Source: Reaver Wiki

Comment: But still it takes forever

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the default settings, no.  The speed at which WPS cracking can be performed depends on how fast the AP responds, which is something that is not under your control.